# how to include and use bootstrap cdn in Salesforce Lightning?

Tags: lightning, bootstrap

how to include and use bootstrap CDN in Salesforce Lightning

Comment: Hello Akhil, Welcome to SFSE, what you have tried so far, are you stuck somewhere? Please add the code snippet that you have tried and describe your problem in detail .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

External libraries must be uploaded to Salesforce as a Static Resource.

You'll then be able to load those resources in your custom components using [`<ltng:require>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_libs_platform.htm), with a reference to the Static Resource you created:

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.resourceName}"
              afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}" />
```

It's important to bear in mind that scripts are loaded asynchronously. Your components cannot rely on external scripts being loaded in their `init` handlers; you must wait for your `afterScriptsLoaded` callback to execute.